# deserialization issue - getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am having two servers called Server A and B. I am storing one class called person in Server A's session and accessing that person object in server B.

In server A i am having POJO class for person (ie. Serializable and having serialVersionUID)
In server B i dont have person class, still I want to deserialize that object value in server B.

deserialize code

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream)) {
    return (Map<String, Object>) input.readObject(); // -> **Exception occur here**
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: @veljkost Could you please help?

Comment: Define the same Person class on the other side too. BTW in your code you're actually trying to read a Map and not a Person ?

Comment: I dont want add the Person class in Server B - that is my concern

Comment: Then it's not possible to have an object of that type read on that side because the code on that side has no idea what kind of object this is

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you are trying to achieve. You want server B to deserialise an object without knowing what class it is, and Java's deserialization can't do that, furthermore you are trying to cast an unknown class (Person) into a Map.

My suggestion would be to instead use [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) to transmit data between servers. You should be able to easily serialize the Person class into JSON, and deserialize the JSON on Server B into a Map, assuming that the Map is a map of Person fields, and the values are primitive or String.

Comment: Can u give any example pleas?